# Not able to connect to amazon s3 client using java dsl camel component

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel

```
Not able to connect to s3 using java dsl. 

    XML:    
<bean id="aWSCredentialsProvider" class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
    <constructor-arg name="accessKey" value="user1"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="secretKey" value="xxxxO0Vh"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="clientConfiguration" class="com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration">
    <property name="protocol" value="HTTP"/>
    <property name="proxyHost" value="eos-qa.xxx.com"/>
    <property name="proxyPort" value="9020"/>
</bean>

<bean id="amazonS3Client" class="com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client">
    <constructor-arg name="awsCredentials" ref="aWSCredentialsProvider"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="clientConfiguration" ref="clientConfiguration"></constructor-arg>
    <property name="endpoint" value="http://eos-qaxx.com:9020"/>
</bean>

    Java Route:    
from("file://input?fileName=BIS2GIS_IXG_6.XML&noop=true")
    .routeId("FileStorageRouteId")
    .setHeader(S3Constants.CONTENT_LENGTH, simple("36790"))
    .setHeader("CamelAwsS3Key").simple("BIS2GIS_IXG_6.XML")
    .to("aws-s3://fdb-bucket"
            + "?amazonS3Client=#amazonS3Client"
            + "&region=eu-west-1")
    .log("done.");
```

/* com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: This happens when the user sends a malformed xml (xml that doesn't conform to the published xsd) for the configuration. The error message is, "The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema." (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedXML; Request ID: 0a1d2f16:16892c3dac5:83dd9:14e), S3 Extended Request ID: null
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1630)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1302)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4187)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4134)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1720)
            at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Producer.processSingleOp(S3Producer.java:236)
            at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Producer.process(S3Producer.java:85)
            at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor$1.doInAsyncProducer(SendDynamicProcessor.java:124)
            at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:436)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:119)
            at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.HandleFaultInterceptor.process(HandleFaultInterceptor.java:42)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:110)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
            at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.sendToConsumers(SedaConsumer.java:298)
            at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.doRun(SedaConsumer.java:207)
            at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.run(SedaConsumer.java:154)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        2019-04-04 13:36:13,965 WARN  -- Error processing exchange. Exchange[]. Caused by: [com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception - This happens when the user sends a malformed xml (xml that doesn't conform to the published xsd) for the configuration. The error message is, "The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema." (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedXML; Request ID: 0a1d2f16:16892c3dac5:83dd9:14e)]
        com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: This happens when the user sends a malformed xml (xml that doesn't conform to the published xsd) for the configuration. The error message is, "The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema." (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedXML; Request ID: 0a1d2f16:16892c3dac5:83dd9:14e), S3 Extended Request ID: null
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1630)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1302)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4187)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4134)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1720)
            at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Producer.processSingleOp(S3Producer.java:236)
            at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Producer.process(S3Producer.java:85)
            at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor$1.doInAsyncProducer(SendDynamicProcessor.java:124)
            at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:436)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:119)
            at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.HandleFaultInterceptor.process(HandleFaultInterceptor.java:42)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:110)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
            at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.sendToConsumers(SedaConsumer.java:298)
            at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.doRun(SedaConsumer.java:207)
            at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.run(SedaConsumer.java:154)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) */

Comment: what is the version of Camel?

Comment: @Oscerd Camel 2.18.2

Comment: can you try with a newer version? It seems very weird. Have you any reproducer for this?